# Upload artifact bundle to sonatype

Tags: maven, curl, nexus, sonatype

I want to upload an artifact bundle(jar) to https://oss.sonatype.org via curl command. I am facing issues with URL.

```
curl -v -u 'username':'password' --upload-file xyz-version-bundle.jar https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/com/abc/xyz/version/
```

I have tried via above curl command and I have tried many variations in URL but still getting `404 - Repository with ID=&quot;com&quot; not found`.

Note: The bundle jar file contains all files like pom etc. I am able to upload the same bundle via UI.

Comment: You need to give a staging repository or a snapshot repository where you like to upload your jar file..But I recommend to do it via Maven directly instead of using curl to do so...Do you have a gpg key etc. and signed your artifacts for that?

Comment: I want to upload it to staging repository, yes I have gpg keys and I have signed all the files which are part of bundle jar. I am able to upload it via UI, but want to automate the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
curl -ujorlina2 -u $SONATYPE_USER:$SONATYPE_PASSWORD --request POST -F "file=@xyz-"$VERSION"-bundle.jar" "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/bundle_upload"
```

Here `SONATYPE_USER` is the username for `https://oss.sonatype.org` and `$SONATYPE_PASSWORD` is the password for same.

Comment: What is `-ujorlina2`?

Comment: Looks promising but doesn't work for me. I added a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025569/upload-artifact-bundle-to-sonatype-using-curl-500-server-error

Comment: Why is @ significant?

Comment: Because it says so in the official documentation: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-2- Go ask Sonatype tech support if you want to know why.