# Upload artifact bundle to sonatype using curl: 500 Server Error

Tags: curl, nexus, sonatype

I want to upload an artifact bundle (jar) to https://oss.sonatype.org with the `curl` command:

```
curl \
    --verbose \
    --user $SONATYPE_USER:$SONATYPE_PASSWORD \
    --form "file=$BUNDLE" \
    https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/bundle_upload
```

The command was based on this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47460712/766786, I just have the habit of writing all options in their long form (`--foobar`) for better readability in shell scripts. This question is not a duplicate, because A) the given answer there doesn't work for me B) I have another error than the OP of [Upload artifact bundle to sonatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436227/upload-artifact-bundle-to-sonatype).

I get this output:

```
*   Trying 54.173.252.242...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to oss.sonatype.org (54.173.252.242) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.sonatype.org
*  start date: Sep 18 15:02:41 2015 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 24 18:39:12 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "oss.sonatype.org" matched cert's "*.sonatype.org"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user '**********'
> POST /service/local/staging/bundle_upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: oss.sonatype.org
> Authorization: Basic ********************
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 157
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------8790eb977ecbbb15
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2018 14:56:07 GMT
< Server: nginx
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 134
< Connection: keep-alive
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
<html><body><error>The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request</error></body></html>
```

When adding the `--request POST` option, I get exactly the same output, with the addition of this as the first line:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
```

See also https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/ for the reason why I don't use `--request POST`.

What do I need to change in my `curl` command?

Note: The bundle jar file contains all files like pom etc. I am able to upload the same bundle via UI.

Comment: Can you try with `--request POST` option?

Comment: Identical output, with the addition of this as the first line: Note: `Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.` See also daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x why `--request` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: add an `@` in front of the filename, so the `curl` command becomes:

```
curl \
    --verbose \
    --user $SONATYPE_USER:$SONATYPE_PASSWORD \
    --form "file=@$BUNDLE" \
    https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/bundle_upload
```

Output is now:

```
(authentication output snipped)
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 08:02:53 GMT
< Server: nginx
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 85
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host oss.sonatype.org left intact
{"repositoryUris":["https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/**********"]}
```

Comment: Why is @ significant??

Comment: Because it says so in the official documentation: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-2- Go ask Sonatype tech support if you want to know why.